# MP4 File editing

Tags: edit, mp4

I have an mp4 video presentation that contains a lot of moving graphics (arrows, buttons etc.) Can I modify/edit these graphics using the MP4 file or do i need the original file used to create the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the original source if you want to edit it.